# How do I open datagrip as another user on the network in OSX

Tags: windows, macos, sudo, runas

On windows I run the following to start ssms.exe as a different user:
`runas /netonly /user:MyCompany\alice ssms.exe`

On mac I want to do the same thing but I want to start DataGrip on OSX
I tried the following:
`sudo -u MyCompany\alice /Applications/DateGrip.app/MacOs/DataGrip`

However it says that it can't find the user. I am using the same network. Alice is a remote user.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not only starting ssms as an domain user, you are also logging into the database as the user using Active Directory.

So to access the database server, you need to set Integrated Security to true in you database connection string, and pass in your Active Directory credentials in the string as well.

Unfortunately, it seems Datagrip only supports Active Directory authentication on Windows clients. So you will be unable to log into your MSSQL database that requires Active Directory authentication from MacOS

Comment: I also cannot "run as" different user in Windows environment. I use Domain Admin account and I get error: "Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file ....". Am I missing something?